# How can i make the following code work with Foundation 6? I believe it is currently in Foundation 5

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, zurb-foundation-6

I want to create something very similar to this http://codepen.io/naneer/pen/EgAau
but I'm having trouble replicating it in Foundation 6.

HTML

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab data-options="deep_linking: true">
 <dd class="top">
  <a href="#tabs-deeplink-1" data-reveal-id="wines">WINES 1</a>
 </dd>
 <dd class="top">
  <a href="#tabs-deeplink-2" data-reveal-id="wines">WINES 2</a>
 </dd>
</dl>
<div id="wines" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
 <dl class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
  <dd class>
   <a href="#tabs-deeplink-1">WINES 1</a>
  </dd>
  <dd class>
   <a href="#tabs-deeplink-2">WINES 2</a>
  </dd>
 </dl>
 <div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content" id="tabs-deeplink-1">
    <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tabs-deeplink-2">
    <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tabs dd.active a {
  background: #008CBA;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).foundation();

$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
 $(document).foundation('reflow');
 $('dd.top').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried porting it to Foundation 6? What errors did you get, what about it isn't working?

Comment: Why have `horizontal tabs` when you can replace with them with simple `buttons` which can also `trigger` those `reveal modals`? And what you want to achieve looks simple. Go through the `documentation` of Foundation 6 for `Reveal Modal` and that should do.